# Dart, how to create a future to return in your own functions?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

is it possible to create your own futures in Dart to return from your methods, or must you always return a built in future return from one of the dart async libraries methods?

I want to define a function which always returns a `Future<List<Base>>` whether its actually doing an async call (file read/ajax/etc) or just getting a local variable, as below:

```dart
List<Base> aListOfItems = ...;

Future<List<Base>> GetItemList(){

    return new Future(aListOfItems);

}
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you need to create a future, you can use a `Completer`. See [`Completer` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-async/Completer-class.html) in the docs. Here is an example:

```dart
Future<List<Base>> GetItemList(){
  var completer = new Completer<List<Base>>();
    
  // At some time you need to complete the future:
  completer.complete(new List<Base>());
    
  return completer.future;
}
```

But most of the time you don't need to create a future with a completer. Like in this case:

```dart
Future<List<Base>> GetItemList(){
  var completer = new Completer();
    
  aFuture.then((a) {
    // At some time you need to complete the future:
    completer.complete(a);
  });
    
  return completer.future;
}
```

The code can become very complicated using completers. You can simply use the following instead, because `then()` returns a `Future`, too:

```dart
Future<List<Base>> GetItemList(){
  return aFuture.then((a) {
    // Do something..
  });
}
```

Or an example for file io:

```dart
Future<List<String>> readCommaSeperatedList(file){
  return file.readAsString().then((text) => text.split(','));
}
```

See [this blog post](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/09/you-complete-me-unless-you-already-have.html) for more tips.

Answer (score 85):

You can simply use the [`Future<T>value`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Future/Future.value.html) factory constructor:

```
return Future<String>.value('Back to the future!');
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I get the `.value('Back to the future!')` flagged as dead code.

Comment: but in the position of receiving call back, how could we handle the <T> object, in your case a <String> (Back to the future!)?

Comment: This solution was the simplest for me. I did <br/>  return Future<List<MyClass>>.value(new List<MyClass>());

Answer (score 50):

## Returning a future from your own function

This answer is a summary of the many ways you can do it.

### Starting point

Your method could be anything but for the sake of these examples, let's say your method is the following:

```dart
int cubed(int a) {
  return a * a * a;
}
```

Currently you can use your method like so:

```dart
int myCubedInt = cubed(3);  // 27
```

However, you want your method to return a `Future` like this:

```dart
Future<int> myFutureCubedInt = cubed(3);
```

Or to be able to use it more practically like this:

```dart
int myCubedInt = await cubed(3);
```

The following solutions all show ways to do that.

### Solution 1: Future() constructor

The most basic solution is to use the generative constructor of `Future`.

```dart
Future<int> cubed(int a) {
  return Future(() => a * a * a);
}
```

I changed the return type of the method to `Future<int>` and then passed in the work of the old function as an anonymous function to the `Future` constructor.

### Solution 2: Future named constructor

Futures can complete with either a value or an error. Thus if you want to specify either of these options explicitly you can use the `Future.value` or `Future.error` named constructors.

```dart
Future<int> cubed(int a) {
  if (a < 0) {
    return Future.error(ArgumentError("'a' must be positive."));
  }
  return Future.value(a * a * a);
}
```

Not allowing a negative value for `a` is a contrived example to show the use of the `Future.error` constructor. If there is nothing that would produce an error then you can simply use the `Future.value` constructor like so:

```dart
Future<int> cubed(int a) {
  return Future.value(a * a * a);
}
```

### Solution 3: async method

An `async` method automatically returns a `Future` so you can just mark the method `async` and change the return type like so:

```dart
Future<int> cubed(int a) async {
  return a * a * a;
}
```

Normally you use `async` in combination with `await`, but there is nothing that says you must do that. Dart automatically converts the return value to a `Future`.

In the case that you are using another API that returns a `Future` within the body of your function, you can use `await` like so:

```dart
Future<int> cubed(int a) async {
  return await cubedOnRemoteServer(a);
}
```

Or this is the same thing using the `Future.then` syntax:

```dart
Future<int> cubed(int a) async {
  return cubedOnRemoteServer(a).then((result) => result);
}
```

### Solution 4: Completer

Using a `Completer` is the most low level solution. You only need to do this if you have some complex logic that the solutions above won't cover.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future<int> cubed(int a) async {
  final completer = Completer();
  if (a < 0) {
    completer.completeError(ArgumentError("'a' must be positive."));
  } else {
    completer.complete(a * a * a);
  }
  return completer.future;
}
```

This example is similar to the named constructor solution above. It handles errors in addition completing the future in the normal way.

## A note about blocking the UI

There is nothing about using a future that guarantees you won't block the UI (that is, the main isolate). Returning a future from your function simply tells Dart to schedule the task at the end of the [event queue](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a). If that task is intensive, it will still block the UI when the event loop schedules it to run.

If you have an intensive task that you want to run on another isolate, then you must spawn a new isolate to run it on. When the task completes on the other isolate, it will return a message as a future, which you can pass on as the result of your function.

Many of the standard Dart IO classes (like `File` or `HttpClient`) have methods that delegate the work to the system and thus don't do their intensive work on your UI thread. So the futures that these methods return are safe from blocking your UI.

## See also

- [Asynchrony support documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#asynchrony-support)
- [Flutter Future vs Completer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57639378/flutter-future-vs-completer)

Comment: This is a superb answer! And I really appreciate the note about why await will still block the UI in the case of heavy workloads.

Answer (score 7):

@Fox32 has the correct answer addition to that we need to mention Type of the Completer otherwise we get exception

`Exception received is type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Base>>`

so initialisation of completer would become

`var completer= new Completer<List<Base>>();`

Comment: but when the control returns back from that function, how can we handle (receive) the object "List<Base>"?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer for the given question, but sometimes we might want to `await` a closure:

```
    flagImage ??= await () async {
      ...
      final image = (await codec.getNextFrame()).image;
      return image;
    }();
```

I think it does create a future implicitly, even though we don't pass it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple conditional Future example.

```
String? _data;
Future<String> load() async {
    // use preloaded data
    if (_data != null) return Future<String>.value(_data);
    // load data only once
    String data = await rootBundle.loadString('path_to_file');
    _data = data;
    return data;
}
```