# Flutter Future vs Completer

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the difference between `Future` and `Completer`?

I am not looking for documentation part on either, instead I would like to see an example showing the real difference between the two.

Comment: A `Completer` *has* a `Future`.  You'd use it to associate a `Future` with an asynchronous operation that doesn't provide a `Future` directly.  Also see https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-completer-directly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Completer` is a helper class for creating Future whereas Future is a `Type`.

All asynchronous functions return Future, but with Completer it is possible to create synchronous function that returns Future as well. Also you can chain that synch functions with `then` etc.

Completer object is one way process, it's not restartable. It does the job and stops.

```
Future<MyObject> myMethod() {
  final completer = Completer();
  completer.complete(MyObject());
  return completer.future;
}
```

Update:

To give an example, in one of my projects I had to get the resolution info of network images. To do that, you need something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44683714/10380182

In there, as you see, after getting the image we do a resolve process which may take time even though it's not an async process. To eliminate that blocking we simply use `Completer`.

Also the info we need exists inside a callback, so it will be cleaner to use `Completer` in there. Then, we use it via `FutureBuilder`. You can approach different but this is very convenient way to handle.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, I'll wait before accepting it, may I know if `MyObject` is a `Future`?

Comment: `GetItemList() `is the Future, `MyObject` is the Type of the `Future`. So you can `MyObject myObject = await GetItemList();`

Comment: @Volleyball MyObject is just an ordinary object.

Comment: OK, I am accepting your answer but in case someone provides a better answer, I will accept theirs. Hope you don't mind that. Great day :)

Comment: @Volleyball no worries bro :) Time to time I'll update the answer better as much as I figure out more deeply the usecases.

Comment: But what is the use case for 'myMethod?'    why would anyone do that?  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 11):

### Prefer Future over Completer

A `Completer` is a class that is used to create a `Future` from scratch. So unless you really are creating a `Future` from scratch you probably shouldn't be using a `Completer`.

### How to make a Future

You can create a Future without using a `Completer` by using the `Future`'s constructor:

```
final myFuture = Future(() {
  final result = doSomethingThatTakesTime();
  return result;
});
```

Using `Future.then()` is another way to get a `Future`:

```
Future<bool> fileContainsBear(String path) {
  return File(path).readAsString().then((contents) {
    return contents.contains('bear');
  });
}
```

And any `async`/`await` method returns a Future:

```
Future<bool> fileContainsBear(String path) async {
  var contents = await File(path).readAsString();
  return contents.contains('bear');
}
```

The above methods are all recommended over using a `Completer`:

```
// This is harder to read.
Future<bool> fileContainsBear(String path) {
  var completer = Completer<bool>();

  File(path).readAsString().then((contents) {
    completer.complete(contents.contains('bear'));
  });

  return completer.future;
}
```

### How to make a Completer

But if you really do need to use a Completer, the way to do it is like this:

1. Create a new `Completer`.
2. Return its `future`.
3. Tell the completer either when it is complete or when there is an error.

Here is an example:

```
class AsyncOperation {
  Completer _completer = new Completer();

  Future<T> doOperation() {
    _startOperation();
    return _completer.future; // Send future object back to client.
  }

  // Something calls this when the value is ready.
  void _finishOperation(T result) {
    _completer.complete(result);
  }

  // If something goes wrong, call this.
  void _errorHappened(error) {
    _completer.completeError(error);
  }
}
```

The code in this answer comes from the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/Completer-class.html) and from the [Effective Dart guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-completer-directly).