# Flutter - The method 'then' was called on null

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, async-await

I have a flutter project with 2 functions:

```
Future<dynamic> eval(String js) =>
  controller?.evaluateJavascript(js)?.catchError((_) => '');

void _getBottomPosition() async {
    final evals = await Future.wait([
        eval("(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight"),
    ]);
    String bottmPosition = evals[0].toString() ?? '';
    isBottomPosition = bottmPosition;
    print("bottomPosition: " + isBottomPosition);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
E/flutter (14430): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'then' was called on null.
E/flutter (14430): Receiver: null
E/flutter (14430): Tried calling: then<Null>(Closure: (dynamic) => Null, onError: Closure: (dynamic, StackTrace) => Null)
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really know Dart, but could take a guess from a different async background: Your method *eval* is not async, so it will return *null* as a result if controller is null, not a Future of null. This might be a problem for *Future.wait*, which will effectively become `Future.wait([null])`

Comment: ... and if that guess is correct, you could resolve it by adding a default future to your eval implementation, like `controller?.evaluateJavascript(js)?.catchError((_) => '') ?? Future.value<dynamic>(null)`, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423691/dart-how-to-create-a-future-to-return-in-your-own-functions But again, I have little experience with Dart.

Comment: Future<dynamic> eval(String js) async{
  return await controller?.evaluateJavascript(js)?.catchError((_) => '');}

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```dart
Future<dynamic> eval(String js) async =>
  controller?.evaluateJavascript(js)?.catchError((_) => '');

void _getBottomPosition() async {
    final eval = await eval("(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight");
    String bottmPosition = eval.toString() ?? '';
    isBottomPosition = bottmPosition;
    print("bottomPosition: " + isBottomPosition);
}
```

First add `async` keyword to `eval` method then update `eval` call in `_getBottomPosition`.